# Jquery dataTables columnFilter plugin not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am new with dataTable. When I add a filter columns plugin, sAjaxSource is not called. Everything shows OK. If I disable `.columnFilter({` it still works.
This my code:

```
jQuery('#table1').dataTable({
                "aoColumns":            
                    [
                     { "mDataProp": "icon", "bSortable": false },
                     { "mDataProp": "name" , "bSortable": false},
                     { "mDataProp": "description" , "bSortable": false},
                     { "mDataProp": "charging" , "bSortable": false},
                     { "mDataProp": "download" , "bSortable": false},
                     { "mDataProp": "action" , "bSortable": false}
                 ],
                "bProcessing" : true,
                "bServerSide" : true, 
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sAjaxSource" : "application-ajax.html?action=FILTER", 
                "sServerMethod" : "POST",
                "oLanguage" : {
                    "sSearch" : "Filter Apps:",
                    "sLengthMenu" : 'Display <select>'+
                        '<option value="10">10</option>'+
                        '<option value="25">25</option>'+
                        '<option value="50">50</option>'+
                        '<option value="100">100</option>'+
                        '<option value="-1">All</option>'+
                        '</select> records'
                }
}).columnFilter({
                  sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                  "aoColumns": [
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 {
                                     type: "select",
                                     values: [ 'ON', 'OFF']
                                 }
                              ]

              });
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are probably using the "columnFilter" plugin [https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/]. I would make sure you are successfully loading the plugin.

To filter by column manually without a plugin you can follow this example from the https://www.datatables.net/manual/api page:

> API reference documentation contains an example for each API method,
>   along with a detailed description of what it does, what it returns and
>   what parameters it will accept; but let's form the concepts described
>   above into a detailed, line-by-line example of how the DataTables API
>   can be used. In this case we create a select element in the footer
>   cell of each column in the table, which contains the data from that
>   column and will be used for searching the table.
>
> ```
> var table = $('#example').DataTable();  
> table.columns().flatten().each( function ( colIdx ) {
>   // Create the select list and search operation
>   var select = $('<select />')
>     .appendTo(
>         table.column(colIdx).footer()
>     )
>     .on( 'change', function () {
>         table
>             .column( colIdx )
>             .search( $(this).val() )
>             .draw();
>     } );
>
> // Get the search data for the first column and add to the select list
> table
>     .column( colIdx )
>     .cache( 'search' )
>     .sort()
>     .unique()
>     .each( function ( d ) {
>         select.append( $('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>') );
>     } ); } );
> ```
>
> Line 1 - Get an instance of the DataTables API with a single table in its context
>
> Line 3 - Select all columns in the table with the columns()DT method. flatten()DT is used to reduce the 2D array return of columns()DT to a 1D array of column indexes, and the utility method each()DT is used to perform an action on each of the selected columns.
>
> Line 5 - The select element for the column's filter is created
>
> Line 7 - Using the column().footer()DT method to get the footer cell element into which to insert the select input.
>
> Line 9 - Use the jQuery on() method to perform an action when the select element's value changes - in this case searching the table.
>
> Lines 10 - 13 - Use column().search()DT to queue up the search, and draw()DT chaining to the result to update the table's display.
>
> Lines 17 - 19 - Get the data from the column that DataTables uses to search the table using the column().cache()DT method.
>
> Lines 20 - 21 - The utility methods sort()DT and unique()DT are used to reduce the data to a nicely ordered list that you would want to present to your end users.
>
> Lines 22 - 24 - A search term option is added to our select list, ready for use.
>
> As you can see, the DataTables API is extremely flexible, and provides
>   a wide range of options for accessing and manipulating the table.
>   Please see the API reference documentation for a full list of the
>   methods that are available. Furthermore, plug-ins such as Editor can
>   extend the API with custom methods such as row().edit() and
>   cell().edit() among other options.